# C standard I/O vs UNIX I/O basics

Tags: c, linux, unix, io, buffer

Here's a very basic question I have.   In my professor's lecture slide, there is a example I dont really get.

She wrote:

```
printf("u"); 
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "m", 1); 
printf("d\n");
```

...and she said the out put of this code would be:

> mud

I don't get it.  So if anyone understand why this happens, please explain to me.

Reference this question:

```
http://lagoon.cs.umd.edu/216/Lectures/lect17.pdf
```

(in the second last slide page.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`write` is a system call -- it is implemented by the interface between user mode (where programs like yours run) and the operating system kernel (which handles the actual writing to disk when bytes are written to a file).

`printf` is a C standard library function -- it is implemented by library code loaded into your user mode program.

The C standard library output functions buffer their output, by default until end-of-line is reached.  When the buffer is full or terminated with a newline, it is written to the file via a call to `write` from the library implementation.

Therefore, the output via `printf` is not sent to the operating system `write` immediately.  In your example, you buffer the letter 'u', then immediately write the letter 'm', then append "d\n" to the buffer and the standard library makes the call `write(STDOUT_FILENO, "ud\n");`

Answer (score 10):

By default, `stdout` is *line-buffered*; it isn't flushed to the output until it encounters a newline character (or until the buffer fills up).

So the `"u"` sits in the buffer until the `"d\n"` is received.  But the `write` bypasses this buffer.

Comment: I would not say that write "subverts" anything.  The buffer is intact and working properly.  More accurately, write is a system call and printf is a library function.

Comment: stdout is *not* line buffered by default.  *if* stdout is associated with a tty, then it is line buffered by default.  If stdout is a regular file or a pipe (or really anything other than a tty) it will be block buffered by default.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: technically, if stdout _can be determined_ to not be an interactive device, it may be block buffered instead of line buffered.